# Faeria does not run after 1.0 Update on Linux

Tags: technical-issues, faeria

Since 1.0 Update, Faeria (Steam) instantly crashes.

System: Manjaro Linux (fresh install)

`glxinfo32 | grep OpenGL`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 17.0.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 17.0.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

`LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 ./.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Faeria/Faeria.x86_64`: **works**, but unplayably slow.

`MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.2 ./.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Faeria/Faeria.x86_64`: black screen with cursor and sound.

`MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.1 ./.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Faeria/Faeria.x86_64`: instantly crashes.

`./.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Faeria/Faeria.x86_64`:

```
Set current directory to /home/xged
Found path: /home/xged/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Faeria/Faeria.x86_64
Mono path[0] = '/home/xged/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Faeria/Faeria_Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = '/home/xged/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Faeria/Faeria_Data/Mono'
Mono config path = '/home/xged/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Faeria/Faeria_Data/Mono/etc'
displaymanager : xrandr version warning. 1.5
client has 3 screens
displaymanager screen (0)(LVDS1): 1366 x 768
Using libudev for joystick management


Importing game controller configs
```

and `cat .config/unity3d/Abrakam/Faeria/Player.log`:

```
Selecting FBConfig
GLX_FBCONFIG_ID=100
GLX_BUFFER_SIZE=32
GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER=1
GLX_RED_SIZE=8
GLX_GREEN_SIZE=8
GLX_BLUE_SIZE=8
GLX_ALPHA_SIZE=8
GLX_DEPTH_SIZE=24
GLX_STENCIL_SIZE=8
GLX_SAMPLES_ARB=0
GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS_ARB=0
GLX_STEREO=0
GLX_CONFIG_CAVEAT=NONE


Desktop is 1366 x 768 @ 60 Hz
XError: GLXBadFBConfig (error 181, opcode 156/34, serial 53, XID 03a00002, display 0x2876a80
XError: GLXBadFBConfig (error 181, opcode 156/34, serial 56, XID 03a00002, display 0x2876a80
XError: GLXBadFBConfig (error 181, opcode 156/34, serial 59, XID 03a00002, display 0x2876a80
XError: GLXBadFBConfig (error 181, opcode 156/34, serial 62, XID 03a00002, display 0x2876a80
XError: GLXBadFBConfig (error 181, opcode 156/34, serial 65, XID 03a00002, display 0x2876a80
XError: GLXBadFBConfig (error 181, opcode 156/34, serial 68, XID 03a00002, display 0x2876a80
XError: GLXBadFBConfig (error 181, opcode 156/34, serial 71, XID 03a00002, display 0x2876a80
XError: GLXBadFBConfig (error 181, opcode 156/34, serial 74, XID 03a00002, display 0x2876a80
Failed to create valid graphics context: please ensure you meet the minimum requirements
E.g. OpenGL core profile 3.2 or later for OpenGL Core renderer
```

Answer (score 1):

`MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.2 MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=150 ./Faeria.x86_64` **works** (playable), but with texture glitches and slower performance (when steam is off - crashes upon some actions). Those are minimum version requirements to run Faeria. They do not match with the official Faeria SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS at http://store.steampowered.com/app/397060/.

The issue with older MESA_GLSL were shaders (fragment evaluation shader, vertex shader), throwing `0:1(10): error: GLSL 1.50 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, and 1.00 ES`

Update: After 04/11/17 Faeria update, in-game performance is no longer an issue.